# No more sound on my Inspiron 15 3000 series with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound

I've just noticed my laptop no more produce any sound. Neither with the speakers nor with the headphones. Can you help me ?

I tried passing by System Settings, selecting 'Sound' and in the tab that says 'Output' adjusting the output volume in 'Speakers Built-in Audio' without result...

I don't know if it is related but videos seems to go slower than before ...

Comment: Hello Marine1, in order to help out we'll need more information. Did the sound work fine before with Ubuntu? Have you just recently installed 16.04? Open up System Settings, select 'Sound' and in the tab that says 'Output' you'll see something like 'Speakers Built-in Audio'. Try clicking on that and adjusting the output volume. Does that have any effect?

Comment: @pHeLiOn Hello! Yes it worked well with 16.04. Then I tried a program `say` and a few time later it didn't worked anymore but I don't know if it was related ...